# Gett JSON from python API

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, json

I am experimenting with some web programming. I wrote a python API that will make a query to an SQL database and return a JSON. The API works as expected.

On the other hand, I have a controller where I make the GET request to use the JSON.

The GET request is made and the API gets rolling; however, when the API returns the JSON the following appears in the developer console of the browser:

> Failed to load http://localhost:3000/api/s1r2_rep_fis: No 'Access-
>   Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Origin 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

I guess this is due to permissions. My http server is run by python:

```
python -m http.server
```

The controller code is:

```
app.controller("test", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/s1r2_rep_fis")
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.Clientes = response.data;
    });
});
```

Please forgive me if I mix up some terms/technology, this is my first time using html/javascritp/angularJS.

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Comment: has nothing to do with the backend call, you are making a call to a different domain

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean to a different domain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854516/understanding-ajax-cors-and-security-considerations

Comment: My guess is you are loading html page from one port and the python code in another

Comment: @epascarello you are correct, the API is listetint con localhost:3000 and the server runsin localhost:8000. If I change the API port to 8000 I get an error saying that the Address is already in use.

Comment: Just to test your code you could disable the chrome's browser security and try.  Or you can create a proxy to your API. Or host your client in the same domain where you host your API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, this is a server-side issue. Not client side. All you need to do is to add CORS enable header on your server.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

You can also check here how to enable CORS.

[enable-cors.org](https://enable-cors.org)

Comment: I think I get it now, I tried to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956683/enable-access-control-on-simple-http-server, however id did not work