# Loading JSON in D3 v5 via Fetch API in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, fetch, es6-promise

When running the following code in Chrome, `d3.json` callback is not triggered until `pubs.json` is loaded in another browser tab/window. It works when the `d3.json` is pasted into the Chrome browser console, it works if running in Firefox...

I'm using Python's `http.server` on `localhost`.

*Why does it act this way in Chrome?*

dir structure:

```
proj/
  index.html
  pubs.json
```

code:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    ...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            d3.json("/pubs.json").then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "until `pubs.json` is loaded in another browser tab/window" ? Do you have a link to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: Script tag should be inside body tag. Is that only typo while rewriting to this post?

Comment: I know this might be a silly question, but have you checked if you are running a proper server to test that code? Javascript in general has several limitations when not working with proper permissions, and while firefox and safari lets you circumvent this somewhat, chrome doesn't.

Comment: @ManuelAlejandroCaetano probably not "proper". I'm using Python's `http.server`. Thought I've never had this problem before.

Comment: @PierreCapo I mean that – the best of my knowledge – the promise is pending on loading the page. Then if, in another browser tab/window, I load `<host>/pubs.json` the promise fulfills in the original tab/window.

Comment: If it's a CORS issue, maybe enable CORS on Python server? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956683/enable-access-control-on-simple-http-server

Answer (score -1):

Chrome is pedantic regarding `CORS` (`Same Origin`)

Try the following:

```
d3.json(chartURL, {credentials: 'same-origin'}).then(function(data) {
    ....
});
```

If the file is loaded by another tab it can be found in the cache and maybe then the requirements are not that strict any more.