# Flutter http request works on Android but not Chrome or MacOS

Tags: android, flutter, macos, flutter-web, flutter-http

This is the code that I am running:

```
var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        'https://arkiteki.co/api/v1/questions',
      ),
    );
```

Results:

Android: Works

Chrome: `Error: XMLHttpRequest error.`

MacOS: `connection failed`

Same code, different results. I need to get it working on Chrome. What could be happening?

Comment: [It](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278016/11818376) can help you.

Comment: @GursewakSingh perfect!