# Flutter web http CORS issue

Tags: flutter, api, http, cors

I am developing a web application with flutter. The http requests are made with flutter [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) plugin. The requests were working fine before. Recently I am getting a CORS Error like this

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:33121' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've added corresponding headers with my request. Even that didn't help me to figure it out.
I am sharing the code snippet that I've used for testing.

```
`var client = http.Client();
try {
  var url = 'https://www.google.com/';
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  print(response.body);
  print(response.statusCode);
} finally {
  client.close();
}`
```

These are logs that I am getting from the browser console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:33189' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> [www.google.com/:1](http://www.google.com/:1)          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
> errors.dart:299 Uncaught (in promise) Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 963:28                get current
> packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                       
> dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                              runUnary
> dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
> dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
> dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
> dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 557:7                                         [_complete]
> dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
> dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1587:7                                             
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
> dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37341:58

I've tried adding these header information with my request. But this also didn't work.

```
`var client = http.Client();
try {
  var url = 'https://www.google.com/';
  var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: <String, String> {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
      },
    );
  print(response.body);
  print(response.statusCode);`
```

Comment: None of those `Access-Control-Allow-*` belong in a request; they're response headers.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278016/11818376) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

`flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`
docs https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/renderers