# no response coming back from python httpserver to javasacript request

Tags: javascript, python, http, server, responsetext

No response (status, responseText) is coming back from python httpserver "example" to javasacript request. javasacript request seems to be okay, but it is not getting from HTTP server "example".
Any advice would be much appreciated.

---

XML HTTP Request in Javascript

---

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           x = this.responseText
        }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/example', true);
    xhr.send();
```

---

HTTP Server "example" in Python

---

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
     def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        #self.send_response(status.code, status.message)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>GET: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is do_GET of HTTP server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.close()
        #self.wfile.write(bytes("Hello, world!", "utf-8"))

     def do_POST(self):
        # read the content-length header
        content_length = int(self.headers.get("Content-Length"))
        # read that many bytes from the body of the request
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(body)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))
```

Comment: Are you sure the `do_XXX` functions are being called? Add `print()` calls so you can see what they're doing.

Comment: Yes I traced the do_XXX functions through VS2022 debug: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/example" on browser shows [GET: /example ..This is do_GET of HTTP server.]

Comment: I was wondering if < xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/example', true); > is blocked for security reasons.

Comment: Is `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in the URL of the document that's making the AJAX request? If not, the same-origin policy will block the response. You'll see a message about this in the browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I got the message below: index.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/example' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Does this mean that < xhr.open('GET', '127.0.0.1:8080/example', true); > is blocked unless  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is provided?

Comment: Yes. There are hundreds of previous questions about that error.

Comment: Thank you. I even tried this example on Github, but it fails with "File Not Found - 404" and the console indicates the problem as "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" Since I am a beginner here, I would appreciate it if I could get a http server example in Python that works.

Comment: I got the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956683/enable-access-control-on-simple-http-server: The line self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") resolved my problem as below:
     def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.end_headers()

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [Enable access control on simple HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956683/enable-access-control-on-simple-http-server): The line self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") resolved my problem as below:

```
 def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.end_headers()
```